# Umlauts / mutated vowels not showing correctly in Postgresql (difference text type and character type)

Tags: java, postgresql, encoding, heroku, playframework

I have a problem with mutated vowels and postgresql. Playframework is using UTF-8 encoding and so is Postgresql. However mutated vowels like ÄÖÜ are not displayed correctly. They are displayed correctly for normal strings, which are stored in the "character varying" type in postgresql. But those have a limit, so you need the "text" type to store large strings. In Java those are both strings, the second with the @Lob annotation.

The problem is, that those strings stored in the "text" type are not displayed correctly, no umlauts. Any clues on what may be the issue and on how to fix it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is the value of the property file.encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had the same problem today.. just remove the @Lob annotation. 
additionally you can specify the type of column inside the @Column annotation like

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "text", columnDefinition = "text")
public String text;
```